# Email from Salesforce it reach to recipient's spam folder

Tags: salesforce

When we send email from Salesforce it reach to recipient's spam folder.

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot you see the exact reason why your e-mail is put in spam. Basically gmail checks if the ip address the email is send from is allowed to send e-mails from e-mailaddress that have your domain name in it. In this case ofcom.org.uk.

I think you need to add SPF records for (or whitelist) all SF ip addresses that will be sending e-mail from your org.